# Oracle DBA, Unique situation with ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

I am facing a very unique situation here in Oracle DB.

I am facing "ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied" error while logging in to my Oracle user using sqlplus.

Basic information about the system:

- Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production.
- 2 database servers in cluster environment using Oracle clustering.

Please note that while using TOAD the user logs in perfectly however. The DB is accessible from toad using the connection details to login an individual db. It fails from TOAD while using the Cluster Scan-IP.

Following steps were performed before i started getting this issue.

I was getting a warning message from the Oracle for my user to change the password as it is expiring. Usually in situations like this i will reuse the same password however in this case it was not allowing me to reuse the same password. So I followed [this link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_28007_password_cannot_be_reused.htm).

Now I am not able to login my user and I am even not able to completely change the password of my user and login.

Please advise with what went wrong.

Comment: I don't know what went wrong, and finding out may be important (so you can make sure it doesn't happen again). However, the fix is easy. You, if this is your own DB, or your DBA if you are in a larger organization, should `connect sys as sysdba`. So connected, you (or your DBA if it's someone else) issue `alter user <user> identified by <password>`. If you are doing this, enter your preferred password. If it's a DBA let them give you whatever password they want, then log in with that password and change it to whatever you want. It is odd though that sqlplus will not work when Toad does.

Comment: Hello mathguy, I already tried that with sysdba access. Anyway will let you know once i debug and figure out the issue.

Comment: It sounds as if SQL\*Plus is now pointing to a different database? Are you able to log in as SYSDBA and check something, perhaps tables in your actual user's schema to see if you are in fact in the same database you are seeing from Toad? For example, say your username is PORING. Log in as PORING in Toad and `create table mathguy (id number)`. Then log in as SYSDBA through SQL\*Plus, if you still can, and `select table_name from dba_tables where owner = 'PORING' and table_name = 'MATHGUY'`. Does that work?

Comment: @pOrinG I vaguely recall encountering a similar issue a couple of years ago.  I would check if there are any strange or unusual characters in the password.  If so, you might need to escape them or put in double quotes.  TOAD may do this for you, whereas SQL*Plus may not.

Comment: @mathguy Thanks for your assistance but it was indeed pointing to the same DB.

Comment: @Roger Cornejo You are right. The issue was caused because of special characters. I didn't imagine that "$" would be such a big deal in passwords. Anyway please find a work around for it [here](http://nadvi.blogspot.com/2011/02/oracle-password-with-or-special.html). Thank you so much for the support.

Comment: @pOrinG My pleasure, I'm glad my experience helped you solve this.  Have a nice day!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was caused because of special characters. I didn't imagine that "$" would be such a big deal in passwords. Anyway please find a work around for it [here](http://nadvi.blogspot.com/2011/02/oracle-password-with-or-special.html).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not sure exactly what your problem is, but these are the steps we follow to reuse a password:

- get user profile
- change profile to default
- ALTER PROFILE "DEFAULT" LIMIT PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME UNLIMITED;
- ALTER PROFILE "DEFAULT" LIMIT PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX UNLIMITED;
- change password
- ALTER PROFILE "DEFAULT" LIMIT PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME 120;
- change profile back

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, I understand the basics on how to do it. I am facing a unique situation after doing the above steps. Thanks for replying.